# How to transfer images from Android client to Java server

Tags: java, android, transfer

I am trying to developer an Android application which allows to capture pictures with the camera, and send the pictures to a Java server.

I don't need the picture after, so I do not need to store it in the phone locally.

I was able to successfully to transfer simple text from client to server, but I'm having problems with images.

What do I need to do to be able to send images from the Android client, and should anything special be made in the server apart from what it is doing now?

Comment: Are you using file input streams? Code would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use http request with MultipartEntity.